# Classicthesis citation style (author,year instead of numerical)

Tags: citing, natbib, classicthesis

I'm using classicthesis 4.1 in LyX to write my thesis and I need help with natbib's citation style.

I can't seem to change the natbib numerical citation style to (Author et al., XXXX; Author2 et al., YYYY).

I have this current line, however, I cant find the right place to put it to make it work:

```
\usepackage[authoryear,round,colon]{natbib}
```

Present situation:

[image: present]

Desired result:

[image: goal]

PS. I am aware that the classicthesis manual states:

> Citation format is governed by the natbib numerical style invoked in
>   the document settings of the main thesis file (beware, options
>   chosen in classicthesis-config.tex will have no effect).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to do what you want:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{abcdefg.bib}
@ARTICLE{sievers07,
   author = {{Sievers}, J.~L. and {Achermann}, C. and {Bond}, J.~R. and {Bronfman}, L. and
    {Bustos}, R. and {Contaldi}, C.~R. and {Dickinson}, C. and {Ferreira}, P.~G. and
    {Jones}, M.~E. and {Lewis}, A.~M. and {Mason}, B.~S. and {May}, J. and
    {Myers}, S.~T. and {Oyarce}, N. and {Padin}, S. and {Pearson}, T.~J. and
    {Pospieszalski}, M. and {Readhead}, A.~C.~S. and {Reeves}, R. and
    {Taylor}, A.~C. and {Torres}, S.},
    title = "{Implications of the Cosmic Background Imager Polarization Data}",
     journal   = "Astrophys. J.",
     year = "2007",
    pages = {976-987},
}

@book{goossens93,
    author = "Michel Goossens",
    title = "The {LaTeX} Companion",
    year = "1993",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    address = "Reading, Massachusetts"
}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{classicthesis}

\usepackage[authoryear,round,colon]{natbib}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,citecolor=cyan}% just for the example

\begin{document}

\citep{sievers07,goossens93}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{abcdefg}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Again, thank you for your answer.

I still can't make it work. Where should I put your solution, and which part of it?

What I already have in _classicthesis-config.tex_:

`\PassOptionsToPackage{square,numbers}{natbib}`
`\usepackage{natbib}`

Comment: @user212704 You're welcome. Try removing those lines from `classicthesis-config.tex` and use `\usepackage[authoryear,round,colon]{natbib}` in the preamble of your actual document. The `filecontents*` environment in my example code is not essential (you don't need it in your document); it was just to make my example self-contained.

Comment: After doing that, it seems that my natbib update clashes with a style already loaded. The returning error message:
"LaTeX Error: Option clash for package natbib. The package natbib has already been loaded with options:
  [numbers]
There has now been an attempt to load it with options
  [authoryear,round,colon]
Adding the global options:
  numbers,authoryear,round,colon
to your \documentclass declaration may fix this."
However, I can't find where the natbib is loaded.

Comment: @user212704 Then remove that line from your document and load the class with the global options: `\documentclass[authoryear,round,colon]{scrbook}`.

Comment: @user212704 in the default `classicthesis-config.tex` natbib is loaded in line 83: `\PassOptionsToPackage{square,numbers}{natbib}
 \usepackage{natbib}`. If you have the default file, you could also do the change there.

Comment: I use classicthesis as documentclass, not scrbook (It says I can't load two styles when I try to add your line). Replacing line 83 in `classicthesis-config.tex` doesn't seem to do the job. In `LyX->Document->Settings->Bibliography` I can choose between `Numerical` and `Author-year`. Choosing the latter, I get this: http://i.imgur.com/FzKEaZL.png . Still, I miss the round parentheses and semicolon separator but it seems I made to the author-year.

Comment: Is it possible to use the `\renewcommand{` in anyway?

Comment: @user212704 try this in the preamble of your document: `\bibpunct{(}{)}{;}{authoryear}{,}{;}` right before \begin{document}.

Comment: Somehow, the command you listed (equal to my proposed) did the job, but it started off as brackets, and no semi-colon. I keep your recent comment as a backup should the format change in the future.